# Unity closes on Ubuntu Logout, but does not complete logout. (Crouton on Chromebook)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chroot, ubuntu-unity, ubuntu-14.04

I've got a Chromebook 14 "dual-booting" Ubuntu 14.04 using Crouton with the stock Chrome OS. I've had it like this for a while with everything operating fine. As you know, Linux Distros are kind of watered down using Crouton so last night I decided to run "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" to finish the full installation.

Things went great and I love having all the features of Ubuntu now, but anytime I go to logout, Unity closes, but the log out/switch back to Chrome OS process never completes. I'm stuck looking at the Ubuntu wallpaper with no way to switch back to Chrome OS and I'm forced to hold the power button to shutdown the laptop.

What could be causing this, and how should I go about fixing it? Thanks for the help, I love everything otherwise, and It'd be a shame to have to reset my chroot all because of this one problem that I know can be fixed with knowledge greater than mine.